# JPA insert query generation violates non-null constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jhipster

I am trying to insert a value using spring-jpa in a table defined as (in Postgresql)

```
CREATE TABLE T_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT 
(id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
principal VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
event_date TIMESTAMP, 
event_type VARCHAR(255), 
CONSTRAINT PK_T_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

The entity is defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT")
public class PersistentAuditEvent  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//...
}
```

When my query is executed (Spring Security is executing it), I get a exception saying that I am trying to insert a null value into the table, violating the non-null constraint.

The query is generated as follows:

```
insert into ... (id, ...) values (null, ...);
```

If I remove the id column from the insert statement, then my auto_increment works. Otherwise it doesn't.

How can I control JPA so that it ignores my id in the insert?

Comment: I'm not sure how [`IDENTITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#IDENTITY) works, but for PostgreSQL you should use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` or `GenerationType.AUTO` for `AUTO_INCREMENT`-like functionality. BTW `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not valid in pure SQL in PostgreSQL, use the pseudo-type `serial`, or use sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Try change an ID generation strategy

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT")
@SequenceGenerator(
    name="PersistentAuditEventGenerator",
    sequenceName="PAE_SEQUENCE"
)
public class PersistentAuditEvent  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="PersistentAuditEventGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //...
}
```

PostgreSQL doesn't support IDENTITY columns.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what Spring Security has to do with it. Anyway, in my experience, I don't use AUTO_INCREMENT in the database, so I would remove it; and don't use strategy IDENTITY for generating id, let it default and Hibernate will be in charge of managing the sequence of your id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT")
public class PersistentAuditEvent  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//...
}
```